# Display ng-message on invalid email without using ng-pattern in angular material

Tags: html, angularjs, angular-material

I want to display error message `Please enter valid email.` on invalid email entry but without using `ng-pattern="/^[_a-z0-9]+(\.[_a-z0-9]+)*@@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,4})$/"`

```
<md-input-container class="md-block" flex-gt-xs>
    <label>Email</label>
    <input ng-model="user.Email" type="email" name="Email" md-maxlength="150" required ng-pattern="/^[_a-z0-9]+(\.[_a-z0-9]+)*@@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,4})$/">
    <div ng-messages="userForm.Email.$error">
        <div ng-message="required" class="my-message">Please enter email.</div>
        <div ng-message="pattern" class="my-message">Please enter valid email.</div>
        <div ng-message="md-maxlength" class="my-message">Plase enter less than 150 characters in email.</div>
    </div>
</md-input-container>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As seen [in the email input example of the angular documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Bemail%5D), the `email` property is set on the error object for invalid email adresses. So you can change your code to:

```
<input ng-model="user.Email" type="email" name="Email" md-maxlength="150" required>
<div ng-messages="userForm.Email.$error">
    <!-- all your other messages... -->
    <div ng-message="email" class="my-message">Please enter valid email.</div>
</div>
```